# resizing a UIScrollView with Animation block moves origin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i'm in the process of scrolling a UIScrollView up if the keyboard will hide a UITextField. i reduce the UIScrollView's height if it will be covered up which works fine. but when i try to grow the UIScrollView's heigh (back to original size), the whole UIScrollView moves up the and then animates down to the original size and location. the origin moves up by X amount and moves down to where it should be instead of the height of the view expanding down.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)n
{
    keyboardMove = self.rightScrollView.frame;
    offsetMove = self.rightScrollView.contentOffset;

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [n userInfo];

    CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                          delay:0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^
                     {
                         self.rightScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(self.rightScrollView.frame.origin.x, self.rightScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.rightScrollView.frame.size.width, (self.view.frame.size.height - (self.rightScrollView.frame.origin.y + keyboardSize.height)));
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    if ((activeTextField.frame.origin.y + activeTextField.frame.size.height) > self.rightScrollView.frame.size.height)
    {        
        float contentOffsetMove = (self.rightScrollView.contentOffset.y + (activeTextField.frame.origin.y - self.rightScrollView.frame.size.height) + activeTextField.frame.size.height + 10);

        self.rightScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.rightScrollView.contentOffset.x, contentOffsetMove);
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)n
{
    if ((activeTextField.frame.origin.y + activeTextField.frame.size.height) > self.rightScrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                              delay:0
                            options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                         animations:^{
                             [self.rightScrollView setContentOffset:offsetMove animated:YES];

                             self.rightScrollView.frame = keyboardMove;
                         }
                         completion:nil];

    }
    else
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                              delay:0
                            options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                         animations:^{
                             self.rightScrollView.frame = keyboardMove;
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
}
```

so, when keyboard hides, self.rightScrollView.origin moves up X points and then animates to the location is should be. i need the origin to stay put and the height become more (grows downwards).

any ideas why its behaving goofy?

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue? I have exactly the same problem and cant find a solution for it ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you're still interested in the answer since I see the last activity here was a year ago, but today I stumbled across the exact same problem in iOS 6 and decided to share my solution with anyone still interested.

I noticed the offset by which the UIScrollView moves up is half the size of the keyboard's height, but only if the UIScrollView's content is offset. So my workaround was to move the UIScrollView DOWN with the exact same amount just before the animation, if the UIScrollView's content's offset is greater than 0. This works fine on both iPhone 4 (3.5" display) and iPhone 5 (4" display) for now, but I don't know what will happen if Apple decides to fix this, in case it really is a UIKit bug.

Anyway, here's my code for clarity's sake:

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    if (self.scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, keyboardSize.height / 2, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
        self.scrollView.frame = f;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is potentially a bug in `UIKit` but the way around this is to work with the scrollView's `contentInset` instead of adjusting the frame. So:

Instead of

```
self.rightScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(self.rightScrollView.frame.origin.x,
                                        self.rightScrollView.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.rightScrollView.frame.size.width,
                                        (self.view.frame.size.height - (self.rightScrollView.frame.origin.y + keyboardSize.height)));
```

do

```
self.rightScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0);
```

Comment: this does move the inserts, but does not achieve what i'm looking for. right now, i shrink my frame, move the contentOffset up if the textbox's orgin is greater (ie, is below the frame) then the scroll view's content. your suggestion keeps the scrollview's frame the same and just moves the inserts, leaving some textbox's hidden behind the keyboard.

Comment: Then it's a scrolling issue, is it not? `- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect) animated:(BOOL);` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try spelling out the animation exactly how you want it to happen? I.e. if you want the height to increase, do just that. Instead of

```
self.rightScrollView.frame = keyboardMove;
```

you could do

```
CGRect f = self.rightScrollView.frame;
f.size.height += keyboardMove.size.height - f.size.height;
self.rightScrollView.frame = f;
```

Comment: I have been thinking about this. Here is another idea: it this happens only with a `UIScrollView` why don't you try setting the `scrollEnabled` property to `NO` before the animation?

Comment: Still having this issue myself